# Requesting a JSON format from GeoServer using Openlayers and GeoExt

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs, geoext, tomcat

I am requesting a vector layer from GeoServer using WFS request in JSON format. I have this URL http://myip.com:8001/geoserver/workspace/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=workspace:mylayer%20layers&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application/json.

I want to populate my grid/table in my client side bind to the vector layer. What happens is that I won't be able to see my layers. My question is that, am I still going to use a server proxy?

I am using Tomcat 6 in Windows 7.

Try to see my code:

```
var vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("My Layer");
store = new GeoExt.data.FeatureStore({
    layer: vector,
    fields: [
        {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'description', type: 'string'}
    ],
    proxy: new GeoExt.data.ProtocolProxy({
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: "http://myIP:8001/geoserver/workspace/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=workspace:mylayer%20layers&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application/json",
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
        })
    }),
    autoLoad: true
});

var gridPanel = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    //title: "Feature Grid",
    region: "east",
    store: store,
    width: 'auto',
    height: 100,
    columns: [{
        header: "Name",
        width: 200,
        dataIndex: "name"
    }, {
        header: "Description",
        width: 100,
        dataIndex: "description"
    }],
    sm: new GeoExt.grid.FeatureSelectionModel() 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to use proxy. The only format that allows cross-domain (and cross-port) access is JSONP, not pure JSON.